# JavaFX8 Collision Detection for ImageView

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

When I googled it, many people are using getBoundsInParent() and intersects(Bounds) methods. I am concerned that the bounds of image is rectangle. The MouseEvent works perfect on ImageView(it detects only real image and ignores the transparent background). Like the MouseEvent detection, is there a way to make collision effect using two ImageView objects while ignoring the transparent background?